# Beatboxer? Get on the tiles!

Tags: word, wordplay, letters

The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions - place one tile in each region so that the tiles in any one ellipse can be re-arranged into an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue!

[image]

Comment: Do the letters in each two-letter tile have to be in order in the eight-letter word? Or can all eight letters be rearranged into any order?

Comment: Letters cannot be rearranged within tiles. (At least, in my answer they aren't.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete solution:

> [image: filled-in diagram]

The first word I got (perhaps surprisingly) was

> fighter = PUGILIST.

Realising that "NG" is probably at the end of a word and preceded by a vowel, it didn't take much fiddling to get

> pound = STERLING.

And then, by a process of elimination, the final word must be

> prize = PULITZER.

Oh and the title?

> "Beatboxer" means a boxer who beats people, not the other meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The words are

> PULITZER prize, PUGILIST fighter, pound STERLING

and the pieces are arranged as follows:

> *prize* only: TZ; *fighter* only: GI; *pound* only: NG;
>  *prize fighter* only: PU; *prize pound*: ER; *pound fighter*: ST;
>  all three: LI.

Comment: Just 40 seconds in it :-)

Comment: So it would seem.